# How to use Go to create account and add/remove friend in ejabberd?

Tags: go, xmpp, ejabberd

I found this library: [golang xmpp](https://godoc.org/github.com/mattn/go-xmpp), and it is quite low level (exposed the details of xmpp protocol).I took some time to dig into it, but quite time consuming. Since,right now,I just need three functions:

1. create account
2. add friend(I think it should be divided into send request/approve request)
3. remove friend

So, can anybody tell me how to do it in this library?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to manage an XMPP server from you backend. I would not use an XMPP bot to perform those task.

You should consider using [ejabberd XMLRPC API](https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc) to perform those tasks. All commands available from ejabberdctl are exposed. It means that you can control a lot of ejabberd behaviour using that API.

Comment: Thanks,actually,It is a sns system,I want xmpp account can be created with user's registration.

Comment: User registration is typically used from client. Are you using Go on Android ? :)

Comment: No,I using go in server side,so when user register an account,a golang service will be called to get it done(validation,save account to info...),I want to this service can create a xmpp account in ejabbered server automatically,of course if user wants to remove his/here account,corresponded xmapp account should be removed from ejabbered server automatically.and similar requirements will apply to add/remove friend.